# Objects in NSMutableArray are all null

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

```
UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SudokuCell.png"]];
NSLog(@"%@", image);
[[self.blocks objectAtIndex:row] setObject:image atIndex:col];
NSLog(@"%@", [[self.blocks objectAtIndex:row] objectAtIndex:col]);
```

Is the code that I'm running. The first NSLog prints a UIImageView object, and the second NSLog prints (null). Why does the second NSLog not print the same thing as the first one?

The array self.blocks is initialized as such:

```
self.blocks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: 9];
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    [self.blocks addObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:9]];
}
```

Comment: what are the values of row and col?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSMutableArray` doesn't have a `setObject:atIndex:` method. You should use `insertObject:atIndex:` instead. Note, that the index can't be higher than the array's count (not the capacity) eg. it won't automatically fill up your array with "empty" values.

Comment: What is this setObject:atIndexedSubscript: then? That might have been what confused me

Comment: That's called when you use the new array literals: `myArray[index] = object;`

Comment: Didn't end up to be the problem. Problem was I thought I was initializing the array, but in reality the initialize wasn't getting called so it was never initialized.